# solana-test-validator Illegal Instruction

Tags: validator

So I didnt have AVX2 support in my WSL2 so I decided to clone and then compile the latest repo with the cargo-install-all.sh script. After all that when i run `solana-test-validator` i get this

```
Ledger location: test-ledger
Log: test-ledger/validator.log
⠁ Initializing...
Illegal instruction
```

Here is the validator log

````
[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2022-07-15T15:27:21.766890200Z [0m[32mINFO [0m solana_test_validator[0m[38;5;8m][0m Starting validator with: ArgsOs {
        inner: [
            "solana-test-validator",
        ],
    }
[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2022-07-15T15:27:21.767221600Z [0m[33mWARN [0m solana_perf[0m[38;5;8m][0m CUDA is disabled
[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2022-07-15T15:27:21.767271800Z [0m[32mINFO [0m solana_perf[0m[38;5;8m][0m AVX detected
[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2022-07-15T15:27:21.782079100Z [0m[32mINFO [0m solana_faucet::faucet[0m[38;5;8m][0m Faucet started. Listening on: 0.0.0.0:9900
[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2022-07-15T15:27:21.782179800Z [0m[32mINFO [0m solana_faucet::faucet[0m[38;5;8m][0m Faucet account address: BCpecVHpmjrebssHnt2aLrKiZLMAP6h9uirWKvRZ4qqR
[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2022-07-15T15:27:21.811610300Z [0m[1m[31mERROR[0m solana_ledger::blockstore[0m[38;5;8m][0m Unable to increase the maximum open file descriptor limit to 1000000 from 4096
[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2022-07-15T15:27:21.811699400Z [0m[32mINFO [0m solana_ledger::blockstore[0m[38;5;8m][0m Maximum open file descriptors: 4096
[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2022-07-15T15:27:21.811818500Z [0m[32mINFO [0m solana_ledger::blockstore[0m[38;5;8m][0m Opening database at "test-ledger/rocksdb"
[0m[38;5;8m[[0m2022-07-15T15:27:34.672767800Z [0m[32mINFO [0m solana_ledger::blockstore[0m[38;5;8m][0m "test-ledger/rocksdb" open took 12.9s```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your validator log has a detailed description of the error.

I think it's better to use the current mainnet-beta/testnet version instead of top of the master. Use `git checkout v1.9.29` before building, for example.

Comment: added the log, please see

Comment: That worked, looks like theres something wrong with the newer versions of solana cli

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Did you uninstall the precompiled binaries first?  Check that you're running the self-built binary with `which solana-test-validator`

Comment: Im fairly certain this was the newly compiled binary. The precompiled binary had a different error of "avx2 not supported, please compile binary yourself" or something along those lines. And I removed the old binaries from my path